# jQuery Toggle First Opened

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to make first toggle opened on page load by adding an extra class to toggle's container. How can I do it?

This is my toggle's script: http://jsfiddle.net/gKAFT/

```
$(".toggle-container").hide();
$(".trigger").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
});
```

Greetings.

Comment: `$(".trigger").first().click();` or setup the CSS for the first block accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the event:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
}).first().click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sAxC7/

Note that `toggle` method is deprecated, you can use `toggleClass` instead:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
}).first().click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B3Luc/

Answer (score 1):

Use the fist selector:

```
$(".trigger:first").next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/cXhQN/

However this doesn't work for SEO since Search engindes don't execute the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {       

    $(".toggle-container").hide(); 
    $(".trigger").toggle(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");
        }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".toggle-container").slideToggle();
    });

    $('.toggle-container').first().show(); 
});
​
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gKAFT/2/).
The thing that's different is the last line `$('.toggle-container').first().show();` which shows the first toggle container.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".trigger:first").trigger("click");
```